# Rendering Archetype with Grid Layout - Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco7

I have an Archetype (1.12.4.0) with one of its properties as an Umbraco 7.4.3 Grid datatype.

Within the razor view that uses the Archetype within its model, I'm using the following, which renders all the HTML markup, but no actual content within each part of the grid:

```
@Html.Partial("Grid/bootstrap3", fieldset.GetValue<object>("grid"))
```

When looking at the json/dynamic object that's getting passed into grid/bootstrap3.cshtml, there are several properties missing from the sections/rows/areas/controls/editor node. The bootstrap3.cshtml and base.cshtml views rely upon the "view" property being present on the editor node, but all I've got is the "alias" property. Is the Archetype not saving the grid json properly??

Here's an "editor" node from a page that uses the Umbraco 7 grid directly (not within an Archetype):

```
sections/rows/areas/controls...
"editor": {
                    "name": "Rich text editor",
                    "alias": "rte",
                    "view": "rte",
                    "render": null,
                    "icon": "icon-article",
                    "config": {}
                  }
```

But the data from the grid nested in the Archetype is:

```
 "editor":{  
                     "alias":"rte"
                },
```

As you can see, all the properties besides "alias" is missing in the Json data in the database.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Not sure if it's possible nor a good idea. Have you tried to meet your requirements with just the grid editor?

Comment: The composite datatype is complex and I do need it to work within a nested/repeatable archetype. I did actually find a workaround to make it work but it's not very elegant. When I have time, I'll pull down the Archetype source code and see about implementing a better solution. So why would you say it may not be a good idea?